# Нужно удалить сообщение от пользователя в беседе

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, callback

Есть массив слов с матом $mat;
Проверка на мат проходит, если мат в последнем сообщении есть, переменная $mat_trigger устанавливается на 'содержат мат';
Нужно, что бы последнее сообщение удалялось, если $mat_trigger == 'содержат мат';
Сейчас есть вот такой код, он не работает, не могу понять почему (остальной функционал бота работает, например пересылает сообщение в ЛС)

```
<?php
case 'message_new':
$user_id = $data->object->message->from_id; // берём userid
$message_id = $data->object->message->conversation_message_id;
$user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token={$token}&v=5.103")); //берём инфо о пользователе в объект user_info
$user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name; // берём имя
$user_message = $data->object->message->text;
$user_message = mb_strtolower ($user_message);// перевод строки в единый регистр
$user_message = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]/u', '', $user_message);// удаляем знаки препинания из сообщения
$words = explode(" ", $user_message);//делаем массив со словами из сообщения
$mat = ['слово1', 'слово2'];//массив слов с матом
$mat_trigger = 'не содержат мат';//переменная-триггер
//ищем мат в сообщении:
foreach ($words as $value_user) {
    foreach ($mat as $value_mat){
    if (strcmp($value_user,$value_mat) == 0){
        $mat_trigger = 'содержат мат';
        break 2;}
}
}
//формируем сообщение для пользователя в ЛС (планирую сделать по триггеру: если был мат, отправлять сообщение)
$request_params_tomsg = array(
'message' => "Привет, {$user_name}! Ты написал: $user_message.<br>Слова в твоём сообщении $mat_trigger. Прошу соблюдать правила нашей беседы!",
'peer_id' => $user_id,
'access_token' => $token,
'v' => '5.103',
'random_id' => '0');
$get_params_tomsg = http_build_query($request_params_tomsg);
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params_tomsg);
//Формируем запрос на удаление сообщения (пока без условия на мат, в теории должен удалять все сообщения, но этого не происходит. код доступа сообщества, поэтому не использую group_id)
$request_params_todel = array(
'message_ids' => $message_id,
'delete_for_all' => 1,
);
$get_params_todel = http_build_query($request_params_todel);
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.delete?'. $get_params_todel);
}//первый Switch, начало не видно, не обращайте внимания
?>
```

Comment: Заметил, что нет токена и версии API в передаваемых параметрах запроса ($request_params_todel) и лишняя запятая - добавил параметры, убрал запятую. Не завелось

Answer (score 0):

В беседах это на данный момент невозможно без токена пользователя и модерации со стороны ВКонтакте